# I can only find 10 block producers with valid SSL. Is that correct?

Tags: block-producer

I want users to have option to select block producers from a list in my DAPP.

But I can only find 10 block producers that has SSLendpoint.

1. I first get block producers from EOS
   https://api.eosuk.io:443/v1/chain/get_table_rows
2. Then I download bp.json from each BP and get information about the nodes.

I was expecting to find 21 producers with valid SSL endpoint. But can only find 10.

I get errors like "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel". And I can't fully understand why some don't have any SSL endpoint information in nodes that are of type "full".

Here is the list on my DAPP: https://captainblackbill.com/blockchain
(it's easy to expand the bpjson on the producers nodes that has error)

The first 10 block producers in my list works very well and very fast.
But I was kind of expecting to have 21.

Can someone please try to explain how this work?

Comment: on your dapp, it says "No valid SSL endpoint in bp.json file for node type 'full'" for cypherglass but i see an ssl end-point in their bp.json and `cleos -u https://api.cypherglass.com get info` works fine for me. are you querying the last full node listed in their list of nodes?

Comment: thanks. Cypherglass is ok. They had two nodes with "full" and the last one with empty sslendpoint - (for-loop without break mistake by me). One other was also affected by that error.

Answer (score 1):

Many of them do

- https://eos.fish/bp.json has an SSL endpoint for their declared full node but it doesn't show in your dapp
- same for https://eosamsterdam.net/bp.json
- same here https://eoscannon.io/bp.json
- http://en.eosbixin.com/bp.json has an SSL endpoint but it doesn't declare their node as `full`
- ...

It seems like you have problems establishing a connection with their servers to download the `bp.json` files rather than it being a problem of them not having an SSL end point for their nodes. Maybe your connection is throttled because you've been making too many requests that have been interpreted as spam or there's a problem with the library you use for SSL connections or with your ISP. Impossible to tell without further details, but according to my results it's not correct that only 10 BPs have SSL end-points

Querying bp.json files that work for me fine e.g.

```
$ curl -0 https://eoscannon.io/bp.json
{
  "producer_account_name": "eoscannonchn",
  "producer_public_key": "EOS73cTi9V7PNg4ujW5QzoTfRSdhH44MPiUJkUV6m3oGwj7RX7kML",
  "org": {
    "candidate_name": "EOS Cannon",
    "website": "https://eoscannon.io",
    "code_of_conduct":"https://steemit.com/eos/@eoscannon/answers-for-two-more-criteria-of-block-producer-candidate",
    "ownership_disclosure": "https://steemit.com/eos/@eoscannon/eos-cannon-block-producer-report",
    "email":"contact@eoscannon.io",
    "branding":{
      "logo_256":"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eoscannon/website/master/eoscannon-logo-256x256.png",
      "logo_1024":"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eoscannon/website/master/eoscannon-logo-1024x1024.png",
      "logo_svg":"https://luckybean.keybase.pub/eos_cannon_logo.svg"
    },
    "location": {
      "name": "Shanghai",
      "country": "CN",
      "latitude": 31.2304,
      "longitude": 121.4737
    },
    "social": {
      "steemit": "eoscannon",
      "twitter": "cannon_eos",
      "youtube": "",
      "facebook": "",
      "github":"eoscannon",
      "reddit": "",
      "keybase": "",
      "telegram": "eos_cannon",
      "wechat":""
    }
  },
  "nodes": [
    {
      "location": {
        "name":"Hong Kong",
        "country":"HK",
        "latitude":22.3964,
        "longitude":114.1095
      },
      "node_type": "full",
      "api_endpoint": "http://mainnet.eoscannon.io",
      "ssl_endpoint": "https://mainnet.eoscannon.io",
      "p2p_endpoint": "node1.eoscannon.io:59876"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You are right - the problem was the security protocol on my server. I added support for Tls12 and then all the SSL-errors disappeared.

Comment: What about eosbixin.com? It uses the old "is_producer: false" and not "node_type". Is "is_producer : true" the same as "node_type : full"?

Comment: @BjørnOmsland they're not the same as full nodes don't have to be BPs, but BPs are full nodes afaik